# Deserialize related object from primary key using Django REST Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

Newbie to Django REST Framework. Serializing is going great. What I'm not clear on is how to deserialize a related object given only its primary key from the database. Here's what I mean:

```python
class ThingA(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)

class ThingB(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    athing = models.ForeignKey(ThingA)
```

Suppose I have a `POST /thingb` REST call to create a new `ThingB`, and the payload contains the name for the new `ThingB` and the `id` for its related `ThingA` (that already exists in the database):

```json
{
    "name": "Name for new ThingB",
    "athing" : 5
}
```

How do I write a DRF Serializer that can also deserialize this payload to end up with a `ThingB` whose `athing` attribute is the `ThingA` object having id=5? I have been trying with DRF ModelSerializers, so I have gotten this far:

```python
class ThingASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ThingA
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'role')

class ThingBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a_thingie = ThingASerializer(source='athing')

    class Meta:
        model = ThingB
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'a_thingie')
```

The documentation's examples for deserializing all use the simple case of an object whose attributes are simple types, and the JSON payload contains everything it needs. What's best practice for deserializing when the resultant object contains a foreign key to another object? I know I cannot do this:

```python
# THIS WON'T WORK
b = ThingBSerializer(data=request.DATA)
```

I thought I could make some progress by overriding the `restore_object` method in my serializer class, but I find that `restore_object` never gets called. Can anyone point me to or furnish an example for this operation? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#primarykeyrelatedfield) it should do exactly what you need — at least in terms of setting the relation from the submitted payload.

If you wanted to return the full representation of `a_thingie` you could subclass PrimaryKeyRelatedField and override `to_native` to do that, instead of just returning the key.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks -- that's the answer. DRF does what I want to do just fine now that I understand it better.