# Django Rest Framework, relationship between a Custom Serializer and an Id field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Given a serializer with a reference to a custom serializer:

```
class IndustryIdeaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sub_industry = IndustrySerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = myModels.IdeaIndustry
        fields = (
            'id'
            , 'sub_industry'
    )
```

I am unable to save changes to this class when I post JSON like { sub_industry: 12 } or { sub_industry_id: 12 }

It does return the right JSON for displaying the data, and I wouldn't change it from that perspective. However changing it to:

```
class IndustryIdeaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = myModels.IdeaIndustry
        fields = (
            'id'
            , 'sub_industry'
    )
```

Gives me the save action (can persist with the simple JSON) I want BUT not the read action (doesn't return all the data associated with that foreign key)!

First am I missing something obvious?  Is there a pattern to deal with behavior I am after - namely read and return the deep tree, but persist with just the Id's

Answer (score 1):

This is for DRF 3.0. I just whipped this up this afternoon, I will follow up if I encounter any unforeseen problems (likewise, let me know if you spot anything wrong! I am fairly new to DRF)

```
class EnhancedPrimaryKeyRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
'''
    This custom field extends the PrimaryKeyRelatedField

    It overrides to_representation (which generates the data to be
    serialized) to use a given serializer.

    This allows other serializers to show nested data about a related
    field, while still allowing the client to set relations by simply
    passing an id.

    To initialize, pass the queryset and serializer arguments.
    The serializer argument should be a Serializer class.

    If the serializer provides Meta.model (such as a ModelSerializer),
    and you wish to use the queryset provided by that serializer, you may
    omit the queryset argument.

    e.g.
    # without queryset
    child_object = EnhancedPrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        serializer=ChildObjectSerializer
    )

    # with queryset
    child_object = EnhancedPrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=models.ChildObject.objects.all(),
        serializer=SomeSpecializedSerializer
    )
'''
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    assert 'serializer' in kwargs
    self.serializer = kwargs['serializer']
    del kwargs['serializer']

    if 'queryset' not in kwargs:
        # Catch any programmer errors
        assert 'Meta' in self.serializer.__dict__
        assert 'model' in self.serializer.Meta.__dict__
        kwargs['queryset'] = self.serializer.Meta.model.objects.all()

    super(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def to_representation(self, data):
    if hasattr(data.pk, 'all'):  # are we dealing with a collection?
        return self.serializer(data.pk.all(), many=True).data
    elif hasattr(data, 'pk') and data.pk:
        return self.serializer(self.queryset.get(pk=data.pk)).data
    else:
        return data.pk
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in that handles this explicitly, but it's now come up a couple of times recently (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527379/deserialize-related-object-from-primary-key-using-django-rest-framework) so perhaps we need to make it easier.

The work-around is to subclass [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#primarykeyrelatedfield), which will handle setting the relation and override `to_native` to provide the full serialisation you're after.

I hope that helps.

Comment: i think the problem I have is that the PrimaryKeyRelatedField only pulls in an array of ID's.  Where as I want an array of Blah Objects.  Am I miss interpreting the field OR your approach (sorry I am a newbie on the Python side coming from a .NET and Java background).

Comment: No, it's a fair question. The idea here is to go from the PKs to the objects, and then I guess you re-use your IndustrySerializer. It's not perfect but it'll work. (There's a thought to have PrimaryKeyRelatedField take an obj instead of the key, which would make this case better but might be worse overall.)